# Configuring hystrix command properties using external properties file

Tags: java, spring, soap, hystrix

in my project in which I used the Hystrix as a library and for Command properties I declared it in another external properties file as follows in the config.properties file:
hystrix.command.ExampleImpl.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds = $ {project.endpoint.example.timeout}, knowing that project.endpoint.example.timeout is set in the external properties file, whereas before this file was in the build with the config.properties file and it went well
and so now I have a default isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds value of 1000 ms.
someone has an idea about this problem.

Comment: when you say file is external, is it in the git repo ? or somewhere else update your question with more details

Comment: thanks for response, but properties files is not on git but outside, in a filesytem directory

Comment: hello @venkat any response for my problem?